# textView resignFirstResponder not firing UIKeyboardWillHideNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a UIView which contains `UITexView` and a Button.
I have a delegate `UITextViewDelegate`.

When I first set the cursor on the UITextView, the delegate function `"textViewShouldEndEditing"` gets called, and this function triggers the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification. So far so good.

When I click on the button, I call the function `[self.textView resignFirstResponder];`, this function then calls the delegate `"textViewShouldEndEditing"`, but the notification `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` never gets called.

I have a listener for the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(_keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Is there anything missing ???

Comment: Could you show your _keyboardWillHide method ?

Comment: I'm using Damiaan Twelker's component https://github.com/datwelk/RDRStickyKeyboardView . But I have added the textViewShouldEndEditing delegate to trigger the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification notification

Comment: You don't have to trigger anything with UIKeyboardWillHideNotification. The point is to register to it, and it will be called whenever you need it. If you use a library i believe you don't even need to register to it, the library does that for you.

Comment: Well the library is only handling the keyboard will show notification, but nothing about the textview resign and keyboard will hide functions! :(

Comment: The library is handling also handling keyboardwillhide, (line 555). I believe there is some sort of conflict between the two.

Comment: Yeah it is registering the method, but why t will not get called on my textview resign function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[self.view endEditing:YES]; is the trick, Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

you should post a notification to the notification center in the following way

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" 
        object:self];

and you can check whether the notification has received or not in the following way

if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"])
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");

Comment: Hi @yashwanth777, I don't want to trigger the notification myself, I want it to get triggered when I resign the uitextview.

Comment: so when you are resigning textview you post a notification as shown above without posting notification notification center will not be called

Answer (score 0):

Is your code is like this, check and let me know

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                   object:nil];

}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note{
        NSLog(@"test");

}
```

Comment: Yes I have registered my notification, but when I resign the uitextview, the notification is not getting called.

Comment: I tried the scenario that you told , and it is working for me ,tell me in which method you have register the notification, and also show your  _keyboardWillHide implementation

Comment: I'm using Damiaan Twelker's component github.com/datwelk/RDRStickyKeyboardView . But I have added the textViewShouldEndEditing delegate to trigger the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification notification